# PDFMake - Arabic text not showing correctly

Tags: javascript, arabic, pdfmake

Possible question for StackOverflow:

I am using pdfmake with Vanilla JavaScript to generate a PDF document containing Arabic text. However, when I download the PDF, the Arabic text is not displayed correctly. Instead, I get a garbled reversed text. Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
var arabicText = document
    .getElementById(id2)
    .getElementsByTagName("p")[0].textContent;

var docDefinition = {
    content: [
        { text: arabicText, style: "arabic" },
    ],
    styles: {
        arabic: {
            font: "Naksh",
            alignment: "right",
            direction: "rtl",
            rtl: true,
        },
    },
};
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("myDocument.pdf");
```

This is the original text in Arabic:
النَّهَاوَنْدِيُّ سَنَةَ ثَلَاثٍ وَسَبْعِينَ وَمَائَتَيْنِ

But this is the result I'm getting once I've downloaded the PDF:
وَمَائَتَيْنِ، وَسَبْعِينَ ثَلَاثٍ سَنَةَ النَّهَاوَنْدِيُّ

Also this is the font I'm using in pdfMake if it helps in the question:

```
pdfMake.fonts = {
    Naksh: {
      normal: "UthmanTahaNaskh.ttf",
      bold: "UthmanTahaNaskh.ttf",
      italics: "UthmanTahaNaskh.ttf",
      bolditalics: "UthmanTahaNaskh.ttf",
    },
  };
```

I've tried setting these as parameters for the style of the text:

```
alignment: "right",
            direction: "rtl",
            rtl: true,
```

I've also tried looking around the web but can not find anything

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your Arabic string to RTL using a function.

Attaching code sample for reference:

```
const convertTextToRtl = (text) => {
    return text.split(" ").reverse().join(" ");
}
```

Comment: it shows the correct output for small sentences, but when I have a long sentence that breaks into multiple lines, the lines are shown in reverse order, any idea how to solve that?

Comment: @ShamimFahad did you find any solution? i have same problem.

Comment: @SaghiShiri no i didn't actually and implemented a solution in the frontend using react-pdf